# Pandas kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I tried to load a CSV file with 43186 rows using this code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)
```

it outputs

```
Skipping line 2574: field larger than field limit (131072)
Skipping line 892: Expected 13 fields in line 892, saw 15
Skipping line 6376: Expected 13 fields in line 6376, saw 15
Skipping line 35433: Expected 13 fields in line 35433, saw 15
```

before the kernel eventually dies. I tried with some other larger CSVs, the same exact code works for the others. how can I fix this? I'm ok with skipping the lines. I tried to increase the limit with `csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)`
but it doesn't work either. I skimmed from line 35433 through the end, no more bad lines there, and if there do exist bad lines, it should be skipped by the `error_bad_lines=False`, right? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> field larger than field limit (131072)

This probably means that multiple (a lot of) lines are seen as one multiline field by the parser.

So there must be something wrong with the quoting in the csv file.

One solution (apart from fixing the csv file) could be to somehow tell the parser not to use/scan multiline fields - this would then mark that line as invalid.

Or maybe the csv file does not use quoted fields at all (which would allow for quotes inside fields). In this case you should tell the parser the fields are not quoted.

Comment: hello @Danny_ds, thank you! I cleaned up the CSV already, all are correctly comma separated, no multiline cases and no bad quotes. the line with > field limit indeed has a very very long string value in a column. I think this long string case should be automatically skipped by `error_bad_lines=False`, no?

Comment: @annisa Hmm, the parser didn't have a chance to read the whole line (buffer full), so maybe it is confused? Are you sure the errors came in that order? (line 2574, then line 892?).

Comment: yep pasted the output straight from the notebook. maybe pandas first looks for the rows > field limit, then reads again from the top to find the bad lines. buffer full, makes sense, I'm thinking to catch and skip these kind of lines with plain conditioning